# How to run a timer from background thread and display the result in UI thread?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker

I am developing a game apps in Windows phone 8 which shows the elapsed time (hh:min:ss) format to the player, so in my UI

```
<StackPanel x:Name="statusPanel2" >
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbTimer" Text=" Time: " />
    <TextBlock x:Name="timerValue" Text="{Binding ''}" />
```

in the code behind I start the timer when game starts

```
private void gamestart() 
{
myDispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan();
            myDispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Each_Tick);
            myDispatcherTimer.Start();
            _sw.Start(); }


private void Each_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 timerValue.Text = _sw.Elapsed.ToString().Substring(0, _sw.Elapsed.ToString().LastIndexOf(":") + 3);
}
```

right now my code is working fine, but only problem it has is it is running in the UI thread and in Windows Phone 8 testing it asking me to check and put into background thread. I tried using Background worker thread but this doesn't update the UI, it is blank. Any help?

can any body tell me how to run in the background thread and still display the time in hour:min:sec format. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    timerValue.Text = _sw.Elapsed.ToString().Substring(0, _sw.Elapsed.ToString().LastIndexOf(":") + 3);
}));
```

For formatting, try

```
.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {}`  piece of code will run in the UI thread, right? and the `Each_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)`  method is also in the UI thread. So what does difference does it make? please answer.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood the original requirement. I thought you wanted to interact with components in your main thread from another thread. You can't do that directly because the 2 threads are independent of each other so you need the Dispatcher to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh lawd

```
myDispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan();
```

You're setting the interval to a timespan of 0.  That's not very efficient.  Probably hammers the hell out of your UI.

What's the resolution of the time display in the UI?  Seconds?  Do this:

```
myDispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

That might be enough to satisfy the check.  There's no point updating the UI at the millisecond level when it only changes once per second.

Comment: Thanks I will do that, actually very poor style of coding, I am improving :)